# Onboard Symbian Programming Language

Tags: symbian

is there any onboard programming language for Symbian that will allow me to code on the device itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PyS60](http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/PyS60) is Python on the Symbian (S60) platform.  I never got around to using it, but I'm fairly sure there's an interactive interpreter available.

They were on Python 2.2 for a very long time, but they finally "upgraded" to Python 2.5.4 recently.

Comment: "Python core is upgraded to 2.5.4" -March 24

Comment: Shows how long since I last checked that out :/

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is your friend: [Developing on Symbian OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian_OS#Developing_on_Symbian_OS).